# bluetooth application development

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth

I want to develop bluetooth(c/c++) applications in linux can any one help me how to and where to start? can any one one provide me proper tutorial ?

Answer (score 3):

[Enjoy](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/).